# C# code with nested Tasks is running slower than same code with Tasks only at top layer

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, async-await

I am running into an issue where Scenario 1 is running slower than Scenario 2 even though it seems like Scenario 1 should run faster because it is not only opening Tasks at the higher level, but also at the inner level. Kind of like a parent child concept (I am aware parent/child isn't actually happening since I believe tasks all run at the same level). Scenario 2 is simply creating Tasks at the higher level and is running faster overall. The only thing I can think of is that it is faster to run less tasks so everything can be processed in parallel rather than trying to open up many more tasks which will most likely cause waiting on an 4 core (8 thread) CPU.

I am trying to figure out if Scenario 2 is always going to be faster or if there is a better way to code Scenario 1 so that it actually is faster than Scenario 2.

**Scenario 1 (has nested Tasks):**

```
public void MainFunction() {
    IList<Task<ProductMaster>> tasks = new List<Task<ProductMaster>>();
    foreach (var x in products) 
    {
        Task<ProductMaster> prodMaster = Task.Factory.StartNew<ProductMaster>(() => RunProductMasterCode(param1, param2));

        tasks.Add(prodMaster);   
    }

    foreach (Task<ProductMaster> tsk in tasks)
    {
        ProductMaster prodMaster = tsk.Result;
        // COMPLEX CODE HERE THAT RELIES ON tsk.Result
    }
}

public ProductMaster RunProductMasterCode(int param1, int param2) {
    IList<Task<ProductSub>> tasks = new List<Task<ProductSub>>();
    foreach (var x in subProducts) 
    {
        Task<ProductSub> prodSub = Task.Factory.StartNew<ProductSub>(() => RunProductSubCode(param1));

        tasks.Add(prodSub);
    }

    foreach (Task<ProductSub> tsk in tasks)
    {
        ProductSub prodSub = tsk.Result;
        // COMPLEX CODE HERE THAT RELIES ON tsk.Result
    }
}

public ProductSub RunProductSubCode(int param1) {
    // COMPLEX CODE HERE
}
```

**Scenario 2 (has single layer of tasks notice I am not creating tasks in RunProductMasterCode()):**

```
public void MainFunction() {
    IList<Task<ProductMaster>> tasks = new List<Task<ProductMaster>>();
    foreach (var x in products) 
    {
        Task<ProductMaster> prodMaster = Task.Factory.StartNew<ProductMaster>(() => RunProductMasterCode(param1, param2));

        tasks.Add(prodMaster);   
    }

    foreach (Task<ProductMaster> tsk in tasks)
    {
        ProductMaster prodMaster = tsk.Result;
        // COMPLEX CODE HERE THAT RELIES ON tsk.Result
    }
}

public ProductMaster RunProductMasterCode(int param1, int param2) {
    foreach (var x in subProducts) 
    {
        // NO THREADING HERE
        var prodSub = RunProductSubCode(param1);
    }
}

public ProductSub RunProductSubCode(int param1) {
    // COMPLEX CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: `prodSub` is local to the `foreach` loop.  Is the complex code supposed to be inside the loop?

Comment: @IanMcLaird sorry I had to make some adjustments to my code. I forgot to show that I was adding to the tasks list then looping through it afterwards when calling .Result. Additionally removed the comment you were talking about because it shouldn't have been there in Scenario 2.

Comment: Any reason why the complex code can't be called as a final step of each task?  Does the complex code require that all tasks have completed?

Comment: @IanMcLaird Correct each time you see Complex Code it relies on all tasks to be complete. So no I can't call it as a final step of each task.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll()` *may* help with this, but I'm not sure you'll be able to do much better than you are already.  You may have just found the point where further breaking down the task onto threads just adds overhead.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a task with `StartNew` only to immediately wait for the result is accomplishing nothing while adding in the overhead of constructing the task, scheduling work on the thread pool, waiting for that thread pool thread to be scheduled, and then waiting for the original thread to be scheduled again after the work finishes.

Just having the original thread do the actual work synchronously has all of the same benefits as constructing that task that you're then immediately waiting on without any of that additional (rather expensive) overhead.

If all of your code actually needs to run entirely synchronously then you shouldn't be using any tasks at all, just run the code.

Comment: thank you for pointing out this flaw. RunProductMasterCode and RunProductSubCode are two very complex functions that take a while to run. Lets say I have 20 Products in my master loop. I prefer to utilize the CPU Cores on the server and process as many products as I can in parallel. How can I adjust my code so it is not running synchronously?

Comment: @BlakeRivell That's going to depend on what they're actually doing, what operations can and can't safely be run in parallel, etc.  It could be as simple as not processing the results until you've started all of the operations, or it could be extremely complex, depending on what is actually being done.

Comment: I apologize, my code was incorrect. Can you please look at it now. I forgot to show that I was adding to the Tasks list then looping through it after. I might make more sense now. I am pretty sure it is doing something correctly because Scenario 2 is way faster than running synchronously without any tasks.

Comment: have you had a chance to look at my code now. I apologize the initial structure was all messed up so I can see exactly why you posted what you did.